# May I know how to turn off DEBUG logging for AWS Lambda Function?

Tags: aws-lambda

May I know how to turn off DEBUG logging for AWS Lambda Function? My lambda function is a small spring boot application. Currently, it is generating a lot of debug log messages, particularly, "DEBUG org.apache.http.wire". Can I turn this off? May I know how?

Thanks,
Ramesh.

Comment: Do you mean CloudWatch logs ?

Comment: I want to have the cloudwatch logs. But I dont want to see DEBUG messages.

Comment: Then you need to disable them from your application - aws lambda has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have the following entries in my log4j2.properties file                                             log=.
log4j.rootLogger =ERROR,LAMBDA

# Define the LAMBDA appender
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=ERROR
log4j.appender.LAMBDA=com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j.LambdaAppender
log4j.appender.LAMBDA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LAMBDA.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} <%X{AWSRequestId}> %-5p %c{1}:%m%n

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080448/logging-in-aws-lambda-with-slf4j - it may give a you a solution - i am not familiar with debugging logs.

Comment: Thank you very much.